# Timesheet class diagram

Tags: uml, associations, class-diagram

I want to build a timesheet application where employees fill theirs daily tasks in .
I have build this diagram and I need some help if it is correct .

- The role is either Scrum master, developer, Product owner, ...
- The task_type are like: production, meeting, tests, ...
- An agent can have different role based on the project he is affected
- A daily timesheet can include different project, for example : an agent can work 1h in project A and 2h in project B

[image]

Comment: your classes only have attributes, is the goal to define a database or an application (which requires behavior) ?

Comment: I will build an application later, I'm trying to have the relations correctly before :D

Answer (score 1):

### Does the diagram meet your requirements?

Let's verify:

- There's a `Role` with a `name` that can be "Scrum master", "Developer", "Product owner" or whatever role you invent in the future.
- There's a `Task_type` with a `name` that can be "production", "meeting", "tests" or what ever type of activities you may be interested in in the futre
- An `Agent` is associated with an `Affectation` which is associated at the same time to a `Project` and a `Role`.  An agent can therefore have different roles based on the project, if the multiplicity of the association-end on the side of the assignment is `0..*`
- An `Agent` can be associated with a daily `Timesheet`, the date of which is specified by `date`.  The association-end would be `0..*` on the side to `Timesheet`, to allow several time sheets for the same agent.
- A `Timesheet` is associated with a `Timesheet_line` which is associated with a `Project`. The duration is indicated by `time` at the level of `Timesheet_line`.  You may therefore "include" different timings on different projects for the same date if the multiplicity is `1..*` between `Timesheet` and `Timesheet_line` at the latter end.

So yes, your diagram seems to fulfil the requirements.

There are however some ambiguities in your requirements:

- Can `Agent` have several `Role` for the same `Project`, or shall the agent have a single role on a project?  In the latter case, more work is needed (e.g. a constraint on the affectation).
- Can `Agent` have several `Timesheet` for the same date or not?  If not, more work is needed (e.g. a constraint)
- Can the same `Timesheet` have several times the same `Project` (e.g. 1 hour meeting and 7 hours development) or even several time the same project for the same task type? If not, more work is needed.
- In absence of a property type, is `time` the start time, a time interval, or a duration?  I assume the latter and would then recommend going for renaming this property `duration`

### Some more thoughts

Interestingly,  your diagram allows an `Agent` to have time on the `Timesheet` for activities (`Task_type`) that do not belong to the assigned role, or even for projects to which the agent is not assigned. This may seem weird at first, but is in fact a valid way to allow to cope with historical data in case of change of assignments (the `Affectation` does not have a validity interval, so if someone changes role, the old role will be lost) which is not incomaptible with timesheet records entered before this change.

`Agent` and `Admin`  seem to be both specializations of a more generic `User`.  The question is then to know whether an `Admin` can also take the role of an `Agent` and enter time sheets, or if the role of `Admin` is incompatible with that of `Agent`.

Passwords should be unknown in the system and no object should know it.  The accepted practice is to keep a private `saltedPasswordHash` property, and have a `checkPassword()` method which compare the hash corresponding to a user input to the hash kept with the object.

The next step in you rater data driven approach, would be to think carefully about every multiplicity at every end of every association, to have an unambiguous understanding of the relationships, and then complete the picture with behaviors.